# How to preselect multiple option with Meteor / spacebar

Tags: node.js, meteor, html-select

There what I want to have :

The user speak the languages 3 and 2.

```
<select multiple>
  <option>language 1</option>
  <option selected>language 2</option>
  <option selected>language 3</option>
</select>
```

For that, I have :

```
<select multiple>
  {{#each isoLangs}}
  <option>{{isoLang}}</option>
  {{/each}}
</select>
```

and

```
Template.profile.helpers({
  isoLangs: function(){
    return [[...]]; // each line of the array is like this : {tag: aTag, name: aName} 
  },
  isoLang: function(){
    return this.name;
  }
});
```

And, in a session value, I have an array of tag, containing the tag of the spoken languages.

How can I link efficiently link those data to add the "selected" option, knowing that my array isoLangs is not directly related to a specific user ?

Thanks you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `_.map` ([docs](http://underscorejs.org/#map)):

```
isoLangs: function(){

    var selectedname = this.name;

    return _.map([....], function(doc) {
        if(selectedName == doc.name) doc.selected = true;            
        return doc;
    }
}
```

Your html:

```
<select multiple>
   {{#each isoLangs}}
       {{#if selected}}       
           <option selected>{{name}}</option>
       {{else}}
           <option>{{name}}</option>
       {{/if}}
   {{/each}}
</select>
```

Comment: If I do well understand :

I return a _.map wich aply to each element of my array, passed as first parameter, a modification.

this modification consists in chacking if the language is selected, doc being the line of the array currently checked. And i return the doc with its .selected value set as needed.

I guess I have to change the var selectedName = this->name, as if I put it like this, all my languages are goind to be selected ?

Comment: It works great. But now, i'd like to do not have only one selectedName, but an array.

Is there a method / function allowing me to check if a value match any of the values contained in an array ?